# Why is temporary file not deleted in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I have compared two files and stored mismatched values in the temporary file. I have referred to this [link](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Replacing_Lines_in_a_Text_File). After that read the values from temporary file and replaced in original file. Finally I have tried to delete temporary file. All the process working fine except temporary file deletion.

I have used following code:

```
page custom twofilecompare
page custom originalwrite
        Function twofilecompare
        FileOpen $0 "$INSTDIR\backup.properties" "r"
        FileOpen $1 "$INSTDIR\orginal.properties" "r"
        #IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\temp.properties" 0 +1 
        #Delete /REBOOTOK "$INSTDIR\temp.properties"
        FileOpen $R0 "$INSTDIR\temp.properties" "w"
        ClearErrors             

        loop:
            FileRead $0 $2
            ${If} $2 ==  "$\r$\n"
            Goto loop
            ${EndIf}
            FindClose $0


            FileRead $1 $3
            IfErrors done         
            strcmp $2 $3 loop here
            here: 
               FileWrite $R0 $2
               Goto loop

        done:
            FileClose $0                                    
            FileClose $1
            FileClose $R0
        FunctionEnd

       Function originalwrite
    IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\temp.properties" 0 filenotfound
    FileOpen $0 "$INSTDIR\temp.properties" "r"
    loop:
            FileRead $0 $1
            IfErrors done
            //do some stuff

    done:
        **IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\resource\temp.properties" 0 filenotfound
        Delete /REBOOTOK "$INSTDIR\temp.properties"**   
    filenotfound:
    MessageBox MB_OK "file not found"
    FunctionEnd
```

Even I cant able modify these three files[temp,backup,original] manually also.If i modify and click save prompt message displayed as **"please check if this file opened another program"**
I have also used file closed after file usage as completed.
Even i have tried this code also

```
Function .onInstSuccess
IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\temp.properties" notfound
MessageBox MB_OK "file exists"
Delete /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR\temp.properties
Goto done
notfound:
MessageBox MB_OK "file not found"
Done:
MessageBox MB_OK "file deleted"
FunctionEnd
```

But the temporary file is not deleted. How to delete temporary this file?

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The originalwrite function is missing `FileClose`

Comment: Thanks.Its worked.After installed  i cant edit bakcup and original property file.A prompt box opened and display  "please check if this file opened another program".but i have closed three files.How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you requesting admin rights in your script?

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin
```

Some applications like Notepad++ will display a "please check if this file opened another program" message if you try to edit a file that needs admin rights to edit (such as a text file in C:\Program Files).